# Maps view coming up blank on certain devices

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Google Maps SDK for iOS to display some markers (in one case) and some polylines (in another case). I'm having the problem that sometimes the map doesn't display at all, but then zooming in and out with a pinch motion brings up the map. Note that my markers and polylines display just fine right from the outset.

So far we've testing on an iPad 3, iPad 2, iPhone 5, and iPod touch 5.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code?